# Google Apps Script JDBC ( specifically to sqlserver) connection problem using DDNS & Port Fowarding

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script I am trying to connect with using JDBC to a sqlserver running on my local machine. I cannot get the script to connect, "Failed to establish connection, check severUrl, username password"
 I have whitelisted the IP ranges specified in the google JDBC Service documentation. I have also configured DDNS and Port forwarding on my router. I can successfully connect to SSMS using the DDNS name. I have also performed a JDBC connection test using a test tool which seems to be successful. See screen shots below. I have tried tweaking the connection url in my script but to no luck! :/ could someone please shed an eye on my code and assist? Thanks in advance.

```
var url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://'+host+':'+port+'/'+databaseName;

  //var testUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://661607384698.sn.mynetname.net;databaseName=COSMOS_FinalBuild;user=sa1;password=*****';


  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tableName;

  try{    
    //var connection = Jdbc.getConnection(url, userName, password);
    //var connection = Jdbc.getConnection(testUrl);
    var connection = Jdbc.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://661607384698.sn.mynetname.net:1433;databaseName=COSMOS_FinalBuild;user=sa1;password=****;");
```

JDBC test:

[jdbc test screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAD4Z.png)

[whitelisted ips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H306d.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNtKO.png)

@Gord: I tried using the 3 argument getConnection method again. my url output is seen below as seen in the google script debugger.
[url output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBb8A.png)

```
var url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://'+host+':'+port+'/'+databaseName;
var sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + tableName;

try{    
  var connection = Jdbc.getConnection(url, userName, password);
```

Google Cloud Platform Log - stacktrace:

```
{
 insertId:  "-bmwmk9e8vn1l"  
 jsonPayload: {
  context: {
   reportLocation: {
    filePath:  "Code"     
    functionName:  "readFromTable"     
    lineNumber:  26     
   }
  }
  message:  "Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.
    at readFromTable(Code:26)
"   
  serviceContext: {
   service:  "AKfycby9I5yUlkZy8L7IVmNX1JQOAIzO1TKiRR7Lus1BGlI"    
  }
 }
 labels: {
  script.googleapis.com/deployment_id:  "AKfycby9I5yUlkZy8L7IVmNX1JQOAIzO1TKiRR7Lus1BGlI"   
  script.googleapis.com/process_id:  "EAEA1GOziwooUcZfjMqR5zBR-ifoaVNHiz_vL3TZ7yRYfpZvaLDQSTGTPxXhK-aFZHq3aef6Tyc0SRjiDXJmQXVnVbC6hruqXSgOMcRo8QBFsnS0mFtEZBC0y5G_2ZavxEhfg3DJIjvRiBY8jxjlG3RKn0COwEt1Z2S5B-g"   
  script.googleapis.com/project_key:  "MtpHc9N6JeBDF-Yd2tcIAAtFKZI4u1nwX"   
  script.googleapis.com/user_key:  "AAeHopULdD4cfG3US9agmuo+hAm1kYS4RHmnnPR/3kWg5nPeH//brLoUd5kuZbFfezvczZf/RMfm"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/project-id-0363537718702516946/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-03-24T15:49:31.080162988Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name:  "readFromTable"    
   invocation_type:  "editor"    
   project_id:  "project-id-0363537718702516946"    
  }
  type:  "app_script_function"   
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 timestamp:  "2019-03-24T15:49:30.966Z"  
}
```

Comment: Try taking `user=` and `password=` out of the connection string and then pass them as second and third arguments to `getConnection` as in your first commented-out example.

Comment: Hi @GordThompson, thanks I did try that but still unable to make a connection. Edited the question above, does my url look correct? targeting the /database name?

Comment: Do you get an error? If so, what is the error, if not, please describe what does happen.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I have attached a screenshot of the error in the original post. **"Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password".** If I debug the apps script, the code breaks on declaring the connection variable.It remains **undefined**.`var connection = Jdbc.getConnection(url, userName, password);`

Comment: @Rogan88 Unfortunately that is not really helpful for troubleshooting, we need to exception stacktrace.

Comment: The connection attempt should've been logged at  your database and it might show the reason for rejection.

Comment: @TheMaster  Please see above, I have included the stack-trace from google cloud platform logs. I will try dig into the SQL logs this evening, when checking the graph on my mikrotik router, it seemed the connection was not even hitting (getting as far as) the port forwarding rule. If i login to SSMS locally, using the same credentials, the graph shows packets being transmitted, but when running the script, no packets inbound. :/

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Please see above, I have included the stacktrace from google cloud platform logs? I am not sure if that is sufficient? Thank you once again for your input.